# hasBytesAvailable finishing early

Tags: objective-c, json, sockets, cocoa, nsstream

I am sending JSON from my server to my cocoa app.

The cocoa app receives data like this:

```
case NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable:
    NSLog(@"begin");
    if (theStream == inputStream) {
        int len;
        uint8_t buffer[4096];
        NSString* incoming_message = @"";
        while ([inputStream hasBytesAvailable]) {
            len = (int)[inputStream read:buffer maxLength:sizeof(buffer)];
            NSLog(@"\nThe length is -- %d\n",len);
            if (len > 0) {
                NSString *mess = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:buffer length:len encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
                if(mess != nil){
                    incoming_message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",incoming_message,mess];
                }
            }
        }

        NSLog(@"%@",incoming_message);

        // handle icoming message
        [self handleIncomingNotification:incoming_message];
    }
    NSLog(@"end");

    break;
```

The problem is, is if the data begins to be any larger than something like 500 characters it splits into two (the `begin` and `end` log are called twice) so `handleIncomingNotification:` does not work properly as it is passing half the JSON.

When I log `len` I get `1448` a lot and sometimes `1479` and then a one off of `4096`

So obviously `hasBytesAvailable` is not working like it should.

I have tried changing the buffer but that makes no difference.

Please help me come up with a way to fix this. I am surprised this was not an easy google.

---

## Edit from xaphod's answer

I have ended up doing this:

```
case NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable:
    NSLog(@"begin");
    if (theStream == inputStream) {
        int len;
        uint8_t buffer[1024];
        NSString* incoming_message = @"";
        while ([inputStream hasBytesAvailable]) {
            len = (int)[inputStream read:buffer maxLength:sizeof(buffer)];
            if (len > 0) {
                NSString *mess = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:buffer length:len encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
                    incoming_message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",incoming_message,mess];
            }
        }

        [self handleStreamMessage:incoming_message];
    }
    NSLog(@"end");

    break;
```

#### `handleStreamMessage:`

```
NSString*split_message;
-(void)handleStreamMessage:(NSString*)message{
    if(split_message == NULL){
        split_message = @"";
    }else if([split_message length] > 0){
        message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",split_message,message];
    }
    NSLog(@"message:%@",message);
    NSError *error;
    NSData* data = [message dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    if ([NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error] == nil)
    {
        // not finished the stream as not given proper json data
        split_message = message;
    }else{
        [self handleIncomingNotification:message];
        split_message = @"";
    }
}
```

Which appears to be an awful hack that works.

Comment: I think it works as expected, you should probably follow the manual: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Streams/Articles/ReadingInputStreams.html. Accumulate data and wait for `NSStreamEventEndEncountered` before passing your data/json further

Comment: @Andy thankyou but isn't `NSStreamEventEndEncountered` happen when you close the stream. I am not doing this after I send the message.

Comment: Based on documentation `When an NSInputStream object reaches the end of a stream, it sends the delegate a NSStreamEventEndEncountered`. That's the idea of streaming that you read data incrementally. Reading it in single pass is possible but I think you should be receiving `NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable` until you consume entire stream, then `NSStreamEventEndEncountered` should arrive. You can test it yourself in Playground. Don't forget to handle errors and clean up stream properly.

Comment: I just wonder, are you streaming JSON continuously via socket (aka meteor?) or simply sending single JSON object back to client?

Comment: @andy you would only expect the stream to end if the socket is closing after the json arrives. Given that the OP is bothering to use streams, it is safe to assume the json is continuously arriving (like twitter stream api)

Comment: @xaphod if OP is streaming JSON he still has to accumulate JSON and determine boundaries in JSON payloads before feeding them further.

Comment: @andy absolutely. Im about to answer his question with that :)

Comment: You need streaming JSON parser or something like that, you can't rely on `NSJSONSerialization`.

Answer (score 2):

That is not how NSStream networking streams work. If you send X bytes, the receiver will receive N times some amount, which in total will (eventually) be X. N might be 1, 7, or 42 - depends on multiple things.

What you need to do is parse the JSON as it comes in and determine when you have finished receiving enough that it is meaningful. Check out YAJLParser, i use it to do exactly this with the twitter api. Let me get you a link...

.. my fork is here: https://github.com/xaphod/yajl-objc